# What's the song at the beginning of episode 40 of Assassination Classroom?

Tags: music, assassination-classroom

The song at the beginning of *Assassination Classroom* episode 40 starts from 0:06 when Karma gasps, and stops playing at 0:58, then the theme song "Bye Bye Yesterday" starts.

What's the song at the beginning called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解き明かされる謎 
Tokiakasareru Nazo

https://soundcloud.com/xlukis/02-tokiakasa-reru-nazo

A quick note... On Youtube this claims to be from the Second Season OST, which i could not find on Amazon or in fact any of the usual places i go for track lists. there is a version on the First Season OST (track 19 not 2) which is a slower version of the same thing but is not what you're looking for. Sorry i couldnt find you a purchase link but hopefully this will help you in some way.